# How can I locate my disabled train stop among many stops with the same name?

Tags: factorio

I need to locate a specific train stop in my factory but there are a number of problems making this difficult

1. My factory has like 500-1000 train stops in total so locating it manually would be like looking for a needle in a  hay stack.
2. This specific train train stop is disabled so I can't send a train to it (and locate it that way).
3. There are 14 other train stops with the same name. Usually you can put a train stop in a train's schedule and click on the text to locate it, but this only ever locates one (and the same) train stop sharing my sought-after train stop's name.

What can I do to find my train stop?

Comment: For this, we'll need more context as to what kind of stop is disabled. Is it an ore pickup stop? Are all the stops with the same name concentrated in a single area, or dispersed?

Depending on how the stations are spread out, it may be easier or harder to locate them/provide a good way to locate them

Comment: It's a ore drop-off stop. The other stops with the same name are dispersed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a not-so-elegant solution:

Rename all train stops with the same name to a new (but still shared) name. You can do this by adding the stop to a train's schedule, clicking the text to locate one of the stops on the map, and then rename it. Do this one by one. Sooner or later the sought-after stop will be the one that Factorio locates on the map for you.

It is crucial that you finish renaming all train stops even after you locate the one you want to find to not mess up your train scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

Factorio 1.1 (November 23rd 2020) included an elegant solution for this: the Train Overview window. Here's the process:

1. Open the Train Overview with either the `O` key (by default) or clicking the train button above the mini map, second from the right (between the mortarboard and the trophy)
2. In the top left, be sure you're on the Stations tab, not the Trains tab
3. Select the desired station name on the left sidebar
4. Scroll through the tiles in the main panel, looking for an X-in-a-circle icon in the top right of the tile
5. Optional: mouse over the icon to see the reason for being disabled
6. Click on the mini map in the tile to go to that location on the map

[image: Screenshot of Train Overview screen]